# Nice Google Maps Implementation Black and White

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I saw this nice google maps embed implementation in this site http://www.eduardoamaral.com.br/site/contato/

I inspected the code, and it seems to be a framework but I can`t really tell it, can anyone help me find what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code inspection again, look for the line that says `//we define here the style of the map`, that section of the code is what changes the look of the Google Map.

For further customization, you can check out these sites here:

https://snazzymaps.com/ 
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style when declaring a new map, snazzy maps is a good resource for google maps color schemes.

Try the following, just replace this.refs.map with whatever you are using (color scheme from [here](https://snazzymaps.com/style/128277/bluish-universal)) :

```
    var mapStyle =[
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ededed"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "0.00"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-100"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "-67"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": 7
            },
            {
                "lightness": 19
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "-3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#abb1c8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 100
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": "20"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "-26"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "2.33"
            },
            {
                "color": "#f5f5f5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 100
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-19"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.medical",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.school",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": "100"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 31
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#008eff"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -93
            },
            {
                "lightness": 31
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#d2d1d1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": "3"
            },
            {
                "color": "#ebebeb"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "-17"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "lightness": "-15"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            },
            {
                "color": "#e8e8e8"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -93
            },
            {
                "lightness": -2
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#4e00ff"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "-100"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "100"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            },
            {
                "weight": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#e9ebed"
            },
            {
                "saturation": 10
            },
            {
                "lightness": 69
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#e7e7e7"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit.station.bus",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "hue": "#e9ebed"
            },
            {
                "saturation": -78
            },
            {
                "lightness": 67
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
    var map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map,{
      center: center,
      zoom: 10,
      styles : mapStyle
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are just using the Google Maps API and adjusting the style of the rendered map. Here is a link to the API. https://developers.google.com/maps/

You can also dig into what function calls they are making. Go into the developer developer tools (assuming you are using Chrome, but it is similar on other browsers too). Then select Sources on the top bar of the developer tools pane. Find the index file in the sources section on the left of the developer tools pane. Press the {} button at the bottom of the section showing code. This will make the code readable. Then look through it to see stuff related to Google Maps. You can search using ctrl+f too.

I would recommend just reading through the Google Maps API site instead though.